# как из одного массива копировать в другой срезку элементов, без создания нового массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, slice

В коде, когда он копирует из prUsers в users, почему-то создает новый массив в users, как сделать выборку так, чтобы объекты просто копировались без создания массива?

```
class OwnerAuto {
    constructor(name, lastName, phone, brandAuto, cool) {
        this.users = [];
        this.prUsers = [
            {'Имя': 'Кукич', 'Фамилия': 'Васин', 'Марка машины': 'порш', 'Крутость': true},
            {'Имя': 'Фруж', 'Фамилия': 'Инвокерович', 'Марка машины': 'шард кертавра', 'Крутость': false},
            {'Имя': 'Эмгыр', 'Фамилия': 'Эмрейз', 'Марка машины': 'карета', 'Крутость': true},
        ];
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.brandAuto = brandAuto;
        this.cool = cool;
    }
    navigation(){
        let a = confirm('хотите ввести предопределенных пользователей?');
        if(a === true){
            switch(+prompt('можно добавить от 1 до 3, сколько хотите добавить?')) {//создается даунский массив в массиве, поэтому не получается методы применить 
                case 1:
                    this.users.push(this.prUsers[0]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.users.push(this.prUsers.slice(0,2));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.users.push(this.prUsers)
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить три точки перед параметром. Т.е.

```
this.users.push(...this.prUsers[0]);
```

и везде так. Таким образом массив "разобьётся" на отдельные элементы.

Это так называемый **[spread оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**

Comment: премного благодарен!